# Simple concept problem for connected chart on manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

For the topological n-manifold,we can always choose the local chart at each point is connected,that is $(U,\varphi)$ with connected $U$.Correct?

Since we can always find the paracompact coordinate ball as basis for M,such that for each such coordinate ball $U$ exist chart $(U,\varphi)$ on it. And the coordinate ball is connected since ball is connected and $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism, correct?

(I'm not sure whether I make some concept mistake)

Based on this we can conclude if M is orientable,then at each point has a local chart that is either positive or negative orientable correct?Since the domain is connected.

Comment: What definition are you using for orientability? Usually the "original" definition given when learning manifolds is that there exists an oriented atlas, i.e. a maximal collection of charts such that the Jacobian determinant of transition functions between overlapping charts is always positive. Then the question you're asking is true by definition, if I'm understanding it correctly.

Comment: I was reading Lee's smooth manifold page 380 the orientable is given that any point $p\in M$ exist one neighborhood and local frame on it, such that orientation on this local frame admit the orientation given by the manifold.And there is a slightly difference between local chart and local frame,since exist local frame need not to be the frame given by the local chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the definition you gave in the comments: $M$ has a pointwise orientation, which is an orientation for each tangent space $T_pM$ (this is orientation in the sense of vector spaces). The pointwise orientation is continuous, so every point $p$ has a neighborhood $U$ and a local frame $(E_i)$ on $U$ such that at each point, $(E_i|_p)$ is positively oriented (or negatively oriented respectively).

With the definitions out of the way, on to your question. Say the frame $(E_i)$ is based on the connected open set $U$. Let $S^+$ be the set of points in $U$ for which $(E_i|_p)$ is positively oriented. This is an open set since the manifold is oriented (we can find an oriented neighborhood about each point). Similarly, let $S^-$ be the points in $U$ for which $(E_i|_p)$ is negatively oriented. This is also open, and $U=S^+\cup S^-$. Now, appeal to connectedness.

Comment: Hi,for a topological manifold,at each point $p\in M$ we can always find a **connected** coordinate chart around it ?One of such choice is coordinate ball correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: I have another question about the proof of $S^+$ is open,since we have assumed $(E_i)$ is positive oriented frame on $U$ why there still exist some point such that $(E_i)|_q$ is negative oriented on it?